# Can I temporarily take ownership of ALL Windows folders in order to successfully run a PowerShell script on them?

Tags: powershell, checksum, access-denied, ownership

Good morning all. I need to be able to run a PS script to generate checksums of ALL files (well, all files with certain extensions) in ALL folders under C:\ folder. So far I have this simple script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Recurse -Include ('*.bat, *.com') -File |
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |Export-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\hashes.csv' -NoTypeInformation | Format-List
```

The script works fine, except I am getting the following error messages with certain folders:

`Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration' is denied.
At C:\folder\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:1

- Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:' -Recurse -Include '*.bat, *.com' -File |
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...n\Configuration:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
  ```

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied.
At C:\folder\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:1

- Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:' -Recurse -Include '*.bat, *.com' -File |
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
  ```

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup' is denied.
At C:\folder\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:1

- Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:' -Recurse -Include '*.bat, *.com' -File |
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Syst...es\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`
  ```

Now, I have read explanations to this here and on other forums, and I realize that this is due to my lack of ownership of these folders - I get that. My question is can I, via PS, *temporarily* take ownership of these folders, grab the checksums, then relinquish ownership at the end of the operation?

I tried adding the line

`set-executionpolicy remotesigned`

at the beginning of my script, but that makes no difference (I didn't expect it to)

I (actually, the admin who will be running the scans) cannot manually go in and take ownership of each of the folders before running the script then go back and manually relinquish afterward, because of the nature of the operation involved in the actual production scans.

Comment: your include filter is wrong, it should be `-Include '*.bat', '*.com'` instead of `-Include ('*.bat, *.com')`. As for access to certain folders, assuming you're an admin on that local computer, then running powershell as admin should solve that problem

Comment: Thanks for response! Well I am running PS ISE as admin, and I am getting those access denied errors. I just tried running it from just PowerShell with Admin, and I get the same result. As far as the structure of the -Include statement and the file extensions, I saw no noticeable difference between the way I wrote it and the way you suggest, but I will change it, as I am a PS newbie :-)

Comment: Please adjust the block formatting for your error message text as it's difficult to read and understand due to jumping in and out of different code blocks, yet I'm guessing it's all from one output?